# FORTRAN Segmentation Fault

Tags: fortran

The project written in Fortran runs in different machine fine, but when taken to some other Linux machines it does not. It says `segmentation fault` on one of them, and on the other it says `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I did `gdb` of my program, it is very surprising that it points the segfault to the first line in the program where it should print value of a variable kept in module.

I am compiling all of them as follows:

```
gfortran -mcmodel=large -fPIC -fopenmp -lgfortran ...
```

Do you know why this might be the case? The gfortran version is 4.7.2 on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: First enable runtime checks -g -fcheck=all -fbacktrace . Try to run. Then try to run inside gdb. Return here with results. It may be caused by wrong indexes, undefined pointers or other stuff...

Comment: @VladimirF I did with those flags set, gdb still points to the same print statement...

Comment: But the point is which one? Show the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to increase the stack size on those machines.  There are answers on this subject on Stackoverflow.  Check ulimit.

Comment: @torem: Try `ulimit -s`.  If that is not unlimited, set the stack segment size with" `ulimit -s unlimited`.